# Stream pre recorded video as live

Tags: video, stream, live

I want to stream a pre-recorded video as live, preferabel trought a existing service with an upload and schedule api. Or if that fails with an red5 server if this is even posible. Does anyone has experience with a service like this, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.